# How can I "publish" an audio source for consumption by other programs using ALSA and/or Pulse?

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio, gstreamer

I'd like to create a dynamically named audio source that can then be referenced by other programs on my system.  For example something like this:

`gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! alsapubsink name='Test Source'`

and then I'd reference it in other programs like:

`gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc device='Test Source' ! ... ! autoaudiosink`

Of course there is no `alsapubsink` element.  Is there any means of doing this sort of thing using either ALSA or Pulse, or perhaps other tools I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pulseaudio: Make a "null" sink

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=public-sink-1 sink_properties=device.description=Public-Sink-1
```

then use `pavucontrol`, command line options or application menu options (if available) to redirect all sound output you want to "reference" to this sink.

Every Pulseaudio sink has an associated `.monitor` source, so other applications can record or process audio from this associated source in the normal way (i.e., selecting the source with `pavucontrol` etc.).